# Center image inside one of two columns with CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

So I am trying to center my image inside one of my two columns. In this case is the left column. Take the image below for example.

[image]

I got some text in column two, but the image in column one does not look center as the way I envision it. Here is what it is currently looking like right now.

[image]

The red circled is where I want my picture to actually be located.

Here is my code

```css
/* Regular Desktop View */

h1 {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

p {
  margin-right: 50px;
}


/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* End regular Desktop View */


/* Tablet/Smartphone view begins */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  img {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  h1 {
    display: block;
    font-family: sans-serif, arial, verdana, lucida;
  }
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  p {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  /* Home Page */
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

  <style>
    /* Regular Desktop View */
    
    h1 {
      display: none;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 170px;
      height: 170px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    h2 {
      text-align: left;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    p {
      margin-right: 50px;
    }
    /* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
    
    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    /* End regular Desktop View */
    /* Tablet/Smartphone view begins */
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      img {
        width: 170px;
        height: 170px;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      h1 {
        display: block;
        font-family: sans-serif, arial, verdana, lucida;
      }
      h2 {
        text-align: center;
      }
      p {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      /* Home Page */
      .column {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>

  <ul class="topnav">
    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <div class="menu">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>

  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>


  <div class="row">

    <div class="column">
      <img src="img/image1.jpg" class="float-center">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <h2>This is an h2 Title</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
        quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

When I view this in full screen in desktop mode, it is just not how I want it. But when I resize my browser to tablet/smartphone mode, I'm cool with that. My goal here is to center the image in column one no matter how you resize it under it reaches the pixels max-width.

Comment: Add `text-align: center;` to the image's column.

Comment: @Siavas I followed the same steps taken here at W3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_two_columns_responsive and within the row div, there is two column div for the two columns. In the first column div, I put the image and it is not working as I expected. I have `      img {
        width: 170px;
        height: 170px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center; /*NOTE: This is already in my index.html CSS*/
      }`

Comment: @Siavas I think in my code the .column {float: left;} in my desktop view of the styling could be causing this weird phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

As by default `<img>` tag in HTML5 is an `inline-block` element, you can center it by applying the `text-align: center;` to it. This may seem unintuitive as it says *center text to center*, but it actually applies to all content that is of type `inline-block`.

Find below the updated snippet with a new class `.centered` that has been added to the first column, so that only the its contents get centered.

```css
/* Regular Desktop View */

h1 {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

p {
  margin-right: 50px;
}


/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* End regular Desktop View */


/* Tablet/Smartphone view begins */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  img {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  h1 {
    display: block;
    font-family: sans-serif, arial, verdana, lucida;
  }
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  p {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  /* Home Page */
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

  <style>
    /* Regular Desktop View */
    
    h1 {
      display: none;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 170px;
      height: 170px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    h2 {
      text-align: left;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    p {
      margin-right: 50px;
    }
    /* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
    
    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    /* End regular Desktop View */
    /* Tablet/Smartphone view begins */
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      img {
        width: 170px;
        height: 170px;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      h1 {
        display: block;
        font-family: sans-serif, arial, verdana, lucida;
      }
      h2 {
        text-align: center;
      }
      p {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      /* Home Page */
      .column {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>

  <ul class="topnav">
    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <div class="menu">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>

  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>


  <div class="row">

    <div class="column centered">
      <img src="img/image1.jpg" class="float-center">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <h2>This is an h2 Title</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
        quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

A good tip for the future is to keep you HTML separate from your CSS styling – try to have as few (if not none) inline styling and `<style>` tags in your HTML, and reference your stylesheets with `<link>` tags. Learn more about this from [this W3Schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

Comment: Yea for sure. I'll be sure to use HTML and CSS separately to make reading codes much easier.

Comment: @Azazel way to go :) Let me and others know this worked for you by upvoting and marking the answer as correct on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my plan was (*in sketch*). From desktop to mobile.

[image]

[image]

I was able to ask the right question in another forum and I got this answer.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.redd.it/q2iv8opn50kz.jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <h2>This is an h2 tag</h2>
    <p>
      The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
      from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex; /* Where the mobile part begins */
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 50px 0 0 30px;
}

.parent div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
}
```

Now I have it in two somewhat "columns," it works!